# How do I count and add a digit to a specific position if the count if less than expected using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I put together this script were I modified the telephone numbers in a table to remove characters like (,), - and added a country code 55 at the begging of the numbers.

My problem is that the table has some numbers that are missing a specific digit(number 9) right after the(closing parentheses), for example:
index 1 of the original table only has 10 digits and indexes 0 and 2 have 11.

I need to add the member 9 after the closing parentheses to the numbers that only have 10 digits.

Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os.path
import win32com.client as win32

#get header 3 and select columns


#C:\Users\wilso\OneDrive\Desktop\PastaBoletosRelatoro



folder_path = r'C:\PastaBoletosRelatorioVencendoHoje'
file_type = '\*xlsx'
files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

import_file = pd.read_excel(max_file)
#display (max_file)

data = pd.read_excel(max_file,  header=3, usecols=[0,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])

# empty variable
nan_value = float("NaN")
#
data.replace("", nan_value, inplace=True)
data.dropna(subset=["Nome"], inplace=True)
data.dropna(subset=["Placas"], inplace=True)
# reset data frame to index 0


data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

display(data)

# convert integer to string
dataNew = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Nome', 'Telefone Celular'])
dataNew['Nome'] = data['Nome'].str.split(" ").str[0].str.strip()
dataNew['Telefone Celular'] = data['Telefone Celular'].astype(str)
# add country code
dataNew['Telefone Celular'] = dataNew['Telefone Celular'].str.replace(r"\(", "55", regex=True)
# remove parentases
dataNew['Telefone Celular'] = dataNew['Telefone Celular'].str.replace(r"\)", "", regex=True)
# remove dashs from  telephone number
dataNew['Telefone Celular'] = dataNew['Telefone Celular'].str.replace("-", "", regex=True)

display(dataNew)
```

the result is this
ORIGINAL DATA

| Nome | Telefone Celular |
| --- | --- |
| SOS SERVIÇOS | (33)98817-4441 |
| MOACIR DE JESU | (33)9927-4568 |
| PAULO MARCOS | (31)98816-4441 |

CURRENT RESULTS

| Nome | Telefone Celular |
| --- | --- |
| SOS | 5533988174441 |
| MOACIR | 553399274568 |
| PAULO | 5531988164441 |

EXPECTED RESULTS RESULTS

| Nome | Telefone Celular |
| --- | --- |
| SOS | 5533988174441 |
| MOACIR | 5533999274568 |
| PAULO | 5531988164441 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `rjust`. This is a method used for filling a column with a leading 'value', in your case 9. But first you need to split the telephone number and get the part you want to fill

1. `telehpone_number_serie = dataNew['Telefone Celular'].str.split(')').str[1]`

Then fill until all cells has length = 10 with the value = 9

2. `telehpone_number_serie.str.rjust(10, '9')`

All together:

```
dataNew['Telefone Celular'].str.split(')').str[1].str.rjust(10, '9')
```

Then you can add the number between parenthesis and the 55.

```
dataNew['FInal Telefone Celular'] = '55' + df.a.str.extract(r"\((\d+)\)")[0] + df.a.str.split(')').str[1].str.rjust(10, '9')
```